# Concatenation of string arbitrarily in python:

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have to generate the concatenation of the string:

My function has `n` and `stuff` as inputs it has to generate the following arbitrary sequence

Here `N` is the no of input strings to be considered.

**Sample Inputs:**

> N = 3 , stuff = ['x','y','z']

**Sample Ouputs:**

> xy xz yz

**Explanation of output:**

xy -> combination of 1 and 2

xz -> combination of 1 and 3

yz -> combination of 2 and 3

The range of N is not specific to 3. i.e Range of N <= 1000.

**My code:**

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
n = int(input())
stuff = []
for i in range(0,n):
    stuff.append(input())

for L in stuff[0:]:
    for J in stuff[1:-1]:
        k = L+J
        print(k)
```

**My Output:**

> xy
>   yy
>   zy

I understood I failed to implement the indexing in list properly.But also I could not fix this bug.

**Question1:**
Can anyone help me to fix the list indexing in loops ?

**Question2:**
Time Complexity is O(n^2) Can I optimize to O(n)?

Comment: You are generating *permutations*, and the Python standard library has you covered: use [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) instead. The documentation includes a pure-python implementation of the O(n) algorithm used.

Comment: Using permutations would yield both 'xy' and 'yx' as valid outputs, I believe he's looking for combinations

Comment: The tested code for combinations is here [itertools.combinations] (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. Correct indentation is critical to understanding Python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's not what you are looking for. But try this one for beginner:

```
stuff = []
N = int(input("Enter the size of N: "))
for n in range(N):
    s = input("Enter stuff %i : " %(n+1))
    stuff.append(str(s))   

for ss in range(len(stuff)):
    st = stuff[ss]
    for x in range(ss+1, len(stuff)):
        comb = st + stuff[x]
        print (comb)
```

or you can simplify by using `itertools.combination`:

```
from itertools import combinations   

stuff = []
N = int(input("Enter the size of N: "))
for n in range(N):
    s = input("Enter stuff %i : " %(n+1))
    stuff.append(str(s)) 

result = [''.join(i) for i in combinations(stuff, 2)]
print (result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with list comprehensions and [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations    
res = [''.join(item) for item in combinations(stuff, 2)]
# ['xy', 'xz', 'yz']
```

with 2 being the length of your desired combination